# Is it common to have for the fields in a form to have its own class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

sample:

I have 2 tables, department and employees (these 2 table is link via the department_id foreign key in employees). and obviously, department has a one-to-many relationship with the employees table.

I need to create a form that has a subset of data from both tables.

These are fields in the web form.

1. family/surname (from employees table)
2. first name (from employees table)
3. employment start date (from employees table)
4. department (drop-down list of the various departments with department_id as the value return and obviously from the departments table).

I'm wondering if creating a new class for these 4 fields is "best practice"? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just returning one of each, you can simply add them to the Model.  If you are returning a bunch of "rows" of these things, then I would say it makes more sense to wrap the values in a Bean and pass back a collection of instances of that bean.  It makes it easier to look through them on the view-side.

Comment: what if I have extra hidden fields that has nothing to do with the data? something like like emailSubject hidden field which will be the email subject of the acknowledgement email? thanks again

Comment: You can put any fields you want in your bean.  Spring MVC will only set the ones you specifically map in the View, and will not touch the one's you don't map.